# What does tmp_xxx means in java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

Today I was searching the web and found a code in an assembly language of java and I turned it back into java code and found some weird codes like "tmp" what does this "tmp_xxx" means?
here is the code:

```
      private static String encrypted()
  {
    byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[32];
    byte[] tmp8_6 = arrayOfByte;
    tmp8_6[0] = 104;
    byte[] tmp13_8 = tmp8_6;
    tmp13_8[1] = 116;
    byte[] tmp18_13 = tmp13_8;
    tmp18_13[2] = 116;
    byte[] tmp23_18 = tmp18_13;
    tmp23_18[3] = 112;
    byte[] tmp28_23 = tmp23_18;
    tmp28_23[4] = 58;
    byte[] tmp33_28 = tmp28_23;
    tmp33_28[5] = 47;
    byte[] tmp38_33 = tmp33_28;
    tmp38_33[6] = 47;
    byte[] tmp44_38 = tmp38_33;
    tmp44_38[7] = 112;
    byte[] tmp50_44 = tmp44_38;
    tmp50_44[8] = 97;
    byte[] tmp56_50 = tmp50_44;
    tmp56_50[9] = 115;
    byte[] tmp62_56 = tmp56_50;
    tmp62_56[10] = 116;
    byte[] tmp68_62 = tmp62_56;
    tmp68_62[11] = 101;
    byte[] tmp74_68 = tmp68_62;
    tmp74_68[12] = 98;
    byte[] tmp80_74 = tmp74_68;
    tmp80_74[13] = 105;
    byte[] tmp86_80 = tmp80_74;
    tmp86_80[14] = 110;
    byte[] tmp92_86 = tmp86_80;
    tmp92_86[15] = 46;
    byte[] tmp98_92 = tmp92_86;
    tmp98_92[16] = 99;
    byte[] tmp104_98 = tmp98_92;
    tmp104_98[17] = 111;
    byte[] tmp110_104 = tmp104_98;
    tmp110_104[18] = 109;
    byte[] tmp116_110 = tmp110_104;
    tmp116_110[19] = 47;
    byte[] tmp122_116 = tmp116_110;
    tmp122_116[20] = 114;
    byte[] tmp128_122 = tmp122_116;
    tmp128_122[21] = 97;
    byte[] tmp134_128 = tmp128_122;
    tmp134_128[22] = 119;
    byte[] tmp140_134 = tmp134_128;
    tmp140_134[23] = 47;
    byte[] tmp146_140 = tmp140_134;
    tmp146_140[24] = 85;
    byte[] tmp152_146 = tmp146_140;
    tmp152_146[25] = 52;
    byte[] tmp158_152 = tmp152_146;
    tmp158_152[26] = 101;
    byte[] tmp164_158 = tmp158_152;
    tmp164_158[27] = 122;
    byte[] tmp170_164 = tmp164_158;
    tmp170_164[28] = 83;
    byte[] tmp176_170 = tmp170_164;
    tmp176_170[29] = 51;
    byte[] tmp182_176 = tmp176_170;
    tmp182_176[30] = 113;
    byte[] tmp188_182 = tmp182_176;
    tmp188_182[31] = 101;
    tmp188_182;
    String str = "";
    int j = arrayOfByte.length;
    int i = 0;
    if (i < j)
    {
      int k = arrayOfByte[i];
      if (k == 48);
      while (true)
      {
        i += 1;
        break;
        if (k == 127)
          str = str.concat("π");
        else
          str = str.concat(Character.toString((char)k));
      }
    }
    return str;
  }
```

Comment: its a variable name?

Comment: From the little information you've supplied I would assume it is the way the decompiler you used named variables in the bytecode you decompiled. Which decompiler did you use?

Comment: Those looks like byte names.

Comment: I used D2J and JD-gui

Comment: Those aren't actually lines of codes, It's defining the Byte's name.

Comment: It doesn't have a meaning.  It's a dummy name the decompiler invented to call the variable by _something._

Comment: I agree with Louis. The decompiler could not recover its old name.

Comment: In particular, it appears from the strange "renaming" of the variable at each step that the compiler, or possibly the decompiler, had represented the code in static single assignment form (SSA, q.v.) at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the names with "tmp" are just byte names, The compiler couldn't backup its old name so it replaced the name's with tmp.

I have cleaned up the code and here is the code without the tmp code

hope this helps :)

Code:

```
    private static String encrypted() {
    byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[32];
    arrayOfByte[0] = 104;
    arrayOfByte[1] = 116;
    arrayOfByte[2] = 116;
    arrayOfByte[3] = 112;
    arrayOfByte[4] = 58;
    arrayOfByte[5] = 47;
    arrayOfByte[6] = 47;
    arrayOfByte[7] = 112;
    arrayOfByte[8] = 97;
    arrayOfByte[9] = 115;
    arrayOfByte[10] = 116;
    arrayOfByte[11] = 101;
    arrayOfByte[12] = 98;
    arrayOfByte[13] = 105;
    arrayOfByte[14] = 110;
    arrayOfByte[15] = 46;
    arrayOfByte[16] = 99;
    arrayOfByte[17] = 111;
    arrayOfByte[18] = 109;
    arrayOfByte[19] = 47;
    arrayOfByte[20] = 114;
    arrayOfByte[21] = 97;
    arrayOfByte[22] = 119;
    arrayOfByte[23] = 47;
    arrayOfByte[24] = 85;
    arrayOfByte[25] = 52;
    arrayOfByte[26] = 101;
    arrayOfByte[27] = 122;
    arrayOfByte[28] = 83;
    arrayOfByte[29] = 51;
    arrayOfByte[30] = 113;
    arrayOfByte[31] = 101;
```

Happy coding! :)

Comment: @zaph I have already decoded the asii values. It's a raw pastebin link that contains some sort of usernames. I didn't wanted to leak the persons private data who made the code so I didn't included it in here :)

Answer (score 1):

Just the varriable name:
tmp = temp (temporary)

Answer (score 1):

When you decompile a Java bytecode file as you have done, the decompiler will often be unable to find out the original names for local variables and the like.  (The names of local variables are often omitted.  It depends on the original compiler used and the compiler switches).

But the Java language *requires* that local variables have names.  So the decompiler needs to generate some names to put into the source code it outputs.  The names are typically based on some simple pattern.  These generated names have no intrinsic meaning / semantics associated with them.  You (the person attempting to understand the bytecodes) have to ascribe meaning to them by figuring out what the code is actually doing.

---

The other observations is that the decompiled code is not really making a lot of sense.  I suspect that the bytecodes were obfuscated; i.e. processed to make them hard for an off-the-shelf decompiler to decompiler.  Which leads to the questions:

- why are you doing this?
- is it legal?

'Cos if it is illegal, or ethically dubious (like cracking a license key or DRM scheme) we shouldn't be helping you.